# What do the silhouettes mean in the "Koe no Katachi" movie?

Tags: koe-no-katachi

Early in the *Koe no Katachi* movie and in the last scene of the movie where Shoya tears up in the school festival, a silhouette is shown:

[image: The said silhouette]

It's kinda blurry, and this one seems like a silhouette of 2 persons (Shoya and Shoko?), with the other silhouette that only shows 1 person (Shoya?).

I've been looking on the internet but found no information regarding this topic. Perhaps there aren't any specific or symbolic reasons for that, or maybe they are created for aesthetic and bridging purposes, but still, I'm trying not to lose any detail about this movie.

I'm really curious about what these silhouettes mean, and their importance to the movie.

Comment: I saw the light leaking from the bran with holes. It may represent the emotional feelings of the main character ...
It reminds me of the interpretation that it means focusing on Shoya and glass, the sense of peeping into the story of the two, and the image of hope. Director Naoko Yamada is characterized by the use of a telephoto lens to portray characters, and there are many such scenes.

Answer (score 1):

Was wondering that myself. I feel like it was open to interpretation but with potentially a suggestive hint.

I'm not sure, but I'd like to think it's Shoyo and Shoka, maybe holding hands. If you want to dissect it with logic I think it's clear it could be them. But the movie felt like it suggested a theme of love.

But it's kind clear its more centered around moral redemption.

Anyone who's read the manga want to pitch in?